# Feynman-Kac formula on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (the right hand side)

Tags: brownian-motion, semigroup-of-operators

Let $B_t$ be a $d$ dimensional Brownian motion and $V\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$. 
Define the operator $T_t$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ by
\begin{equation}
  (T_tf)(x)=\mathrm{E}_x[ e^{-\int_0^t V(B_s) ds} f(B_t) ].
\end{equation}

I want to show that $T_t$ is bounded on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for each $t$: $\| T_t f\|^2 \leq e^{-2\inf V}\| f \|^2$. But I cannot show this inequality:

\begin{align}
  \| T_t f \|^2 &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{E}_x[ e^{-\int_0^t V(B_s) ds} f(B_t) ]^* \mathrm{E}_x[ e^{-\int_0^t V(B_s) ds} f(B_t) ] dx \\
&= ?
\end{align}

It is clear that $|(T_t f)(x)| \leq e^{-t \inf V} \mathrm{E}_x[f(B_t)]$, but this is dependent on $t$.

Thank you for your cooperation.

***This question is not correct. Example: t=0.***

Comment: **Precisely**, what do you mean by the expectation notation $\mathrm{E}_x[...]$ and why does the stuff within the [...] does seem to depend --at least not explicitly-- on $x$ ? What's the relation between $B_t$ and $x$ ? The question as written doesn't make much sense mathematically. It's probably just a problem of notation though...

Comment: @dohmatob $\mathrm{E}_x[\cdot]$ is expectation with respect to measure $\mathcal{W}_x$, such that $\mathcal{W}_x(B_0 = x) = 1$.

Comment: OK, makes sense. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for expectations](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/In%C3%A9galit%C3%A9_de_Cauchy-Schwarz#Autres_applications), for every $x \in \mathbb R^d$, we have
$$
\begin{split}
|(T_tf)(x)|^2 &= |\mathbb E_x[e^{-\int_0^t V(B_s)ds}f(B_t)]|^2 \le \mathbb E_x[e^{-2\int_0^t V(B_s)ds}]\mathbb E_x[f(B_t)^2]\\
&\le G_{V,t}(x)\mathbb E_x[f(B_t)^2],
\end{split}
$$
where $G_{V,t}(x) := \mathbb E_x[e^{-2\int_0^t V(B_s)ds}] \ge 0$.

Note that if the function $V$ is such that $\inf_{x \in \mathbb R^d} V(x) > -\infty$, then we have the crude bound

> $0 \le G_{V,t}(x) \le e^{-2t\inf V}< \infty,$ for all $t \ge 0$ and $x \in \mathbb R^d$.

Thus, one computes

$$
\begin{split}
\|T_tf\|^2 &:= \int_{\mathbb R^d}|(T_f)(x)|^2dx \le e^{-2t\inf V}\int_{\mathbb R^d}\mathbb E_x[f(B_t)^2]dx
\le e^{-2t\inf V}\int_{\mathbb R^d}\mathbb E_x[f(B_t)^2]dx
\\
&\le e^{-2t\inf V}\int_{\mathbb R^d}\mathbb E_x[\|f\|^2]dx = e^{-2t\inf V}\|f\|^2\underbrace{\int_{\mathbb R^d}\mathcal W_x(B_0=x)dx}_{1}\\
&= e^{-2t\inf V}\|f\|^2,
\end{split}
$$
where

- the 2nd inequality is an application of Jensens's inequality, and
- the last equality is because $\mathbb E_x$ is epectation w.r.t to a measure $\mathcal W_x$ such that $\mathcal W_x(B_0=x) = 1$.

We have thus proved that $\|T_tf\| \le e^{-t\inf V}\|f\|$, for all $f \in  L^2(\mathbb R^d)$.

Thus,

> For every $t \ge 0$, the operator $T_t$ is an endomorphism on the vector space $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$.

**N.B.:** The OP claims one sould be able to do away with the $t$ dependence in the exponential factor in the above bound, but I doubt this...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't  get it. Why $\left|\mathbb E_x[e^{-\int_0^t V(B_s)ds}]\right| \le e^{-\inf V}$? $\left|\mathbb E_x[e^{-\int_0^t V(B_s)ds}]\right| \le e^{-t\inf V}$ is clear.

Comment: Can you be precise concerning which part(s) you don't get ?

Comment: First, I think the R.H.S of $|\mathbb E_x[e^{-\int_0^t V(B_s)ds}f(B_t)]| \le \left|\mathbb E_x[e^{-\int_0^t V(B_s)ds}]\right||\mathbb E_x[f(B_t)]|$ is not valid because this is not Cauchy-Schwartz. $\left|\mathbb E_x[e^{-2\int_0^t V(B_s)ds}]\right|^{1/2}\mathbb E_x[|f(B_t)|^2]^{1/2}$ is correct.

Comment: Second, I don't know the inequality $E[e^{-\int_0^t V(B_s)ds}]\leq e^{-\inf V}$. I think $-\int_0^t V(B_s) ds \leq -t\inf V$ not $-\int_0^t V(B_s) ds \leq -\inf V$

Comment: Ah, I misread some aspects of your question. See update. Are your sure about the $e^{-\inf V}$ factor (i.E without dependence on $t$)  in your sought-for bound ?

Comment: Actually, I can't have confidence in that. I'll think a little more time. Thank you.